# Issue with install in magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2

i buy a kalles theme for magento but wen im try to install base theme in this documentation say this: Note: If you have use old magento 2.4.2 or lower magento version.. You need run command composer require lib for old version magento.

I'm using Magento 2.4.2 and came across the suggestion to run the command 'composer require lib' for my older version of Magento. However, when I run this command, I receive the message 'Could not find package lib'. Additionally, Composer shows me some package options like 'lib-gd', 'lib-gmp', 'lib-bz2', 'lib-icu', and 'ext-zlib'. Could you provide me with more information on how to handle additional dependencies in Magento 2.4.2 and how to enable certain functions or features that may require additional libraries, such as 'lib-gd' or any other mentioned option? I appreciate your assistance and guidance on this matter.